# Change 'parameter' string inside method C++

Tags: c++, string

it is my first question in SO, but I cannot find a good solution for this, not online nor from my brain.
I have a big string of number (over 100 digits) and I need to remove some of its digits to create a number divisible by 8. It is really simple... 
However, lets say the only way to create this number is with a number that ends with '2'. In this case I would need to look for proper 10's and 100's digits and it is at this point I cannot find an elegant solution.
I have this:

```
bool ExistDigit(string & currentNumber, int look1) {

int currentDigit;
int length = currentNumber.length();
for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    currentDigit = -48;//0 in ASC II
    currentDigit += currentNumber.back();//sum ASCII's value of char to current Digit
    if (currentDigit == look1) {
        return true;
    }
    else
        currentNumber.pop_back;
}
return false;
```

}

It modify the string but since I check for 8's and 0's first, by the time I get to check 2's, the string is empty already. I solved this by creating several copies of the string, but I would like to know if there is a better way and what is it. 
I know that if I use ExistDigit(string CurrentNumber, int look1), the string does not get modified, but in this case, it would not help with the 2, because after finding the two I need to look for 1's, 5's and 9's **after** the 2 in the original string.
What is the correct approach to these kind of problems? I mean, should I stick with changing the string or should I return a value for the position of the 2 (for example) and work from there? If it is good to change the string, how should I do it in order to be able to reuse the original string?
 
I am new to C++, and coding in general (just started actually) so, sorry if it is a really silly question. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: My call look like this:

```
int main() {
string originalNumber;//hold number. Must be string because number can be too long for ints
cin >> originalNumber;
string answer = "YES";
string strNumber;
//look for 0's and 8's. they are solutions by their own
strNumber = originalNumber;
if (ExistDigit(strNumber, 0)) {
    answer += "\n0";
}
else {
    strNumber = originalNumber;
    if (ExistDigit(strNumber, 8)) {
        answer += "\n8";
    }
    else {
        strNumber = originalNumber;
        //look for 'even'32, 'even'72, 'odd'12, 'odd'52, 'odd'92
        //these are the possibilities for multiples of 8 ended with 2
        if (ExistDigit(strNumber, 2)) {
            if (ExistDigit(strNumber, 1)) {

            }
        }
        else {
```

EDIT 2: In case you have the same problem, check the function find_last_of, it is really convenient and solves the problem.

Comment: you can create an `unsigned x` from `currentNumber` by using `stringstream::operator>>`. Sorry, I have not seen the part big number. But then, following your remark: `while (x % 8 != 0) x /= 2;`.

Comment: [FYI] Do not use magic numbers. if you want to subtract `'0'` from something then just do it like `currentDigit -= '0';` and now your code is self documenting.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you, i did not know that

Answer (score 0):

The following code retains your design and should give at least a solution if one exists. The nested `if` and `for` can be simplified within a more elegant solution by using a recursive function. With such a recursive function, you could also enumerate all the solutions.

Instead of having multiple copies of the string, you could use an iterator that defines the start of the search. In the code the `start` variable is this iterator.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

bool ExistDigit(const string & currentNumber, int& start, int look1) {
   int currentDigit;
   int length = currentNumber.length();
   for (int i = length - 1 - start; i >= 0; i--) {
       currentDigit = currentNumber[i] - '0';
       if (currentDigit == look1) {
           start = length - i;
           return true;
       }
   }
   return false;
}

int main() {
    string originalNumber;//hold number. Must be string because number can be too long for ints
    cin >> originalNumber;
    stringstream answer;
    answer << "YES";
    //look for 0's and 8's. they are solutions by their own
    int start = 0;
    if (ExistDigit(originalNumber, start, 0)) {
        answer << "\n0";
    }
    else {
        start = 0;
        if (ExistDigit(originalNumber, start, 8)) {
            answer << "\n8";
        }
        else {
            start = 0;
            //look for 'even'32, 'even'72, 'odd'12, 'odd'52, 'odd'92
            //these are the possibilities for multiples of 8 ended with 2
            if (ExistDigit(originalNumber, start, 2)) {
                for (int look2 = 1; look2 < 10; look2 += 4) {
                    int startAttempt1 = start;
                    if (ExistDigit(originalNumber, startAttempt1, look2)) { // 'odd'
                        for (int look3 = 1; look3 < 10; look3 += 2) {
                            int startAttempt2 = startAttempt1;
                            if (ExistDigit(originalNumber, startAttempt2, look3))
                                answer << "\n" << look3 << look2 << "2";
                        };
                    }
                };
                for (int look2 = 3; look2 < 10; look2 += 4) {
                    int startAttempt1 = start;
                    if (ExistDigit(originalNumber, startAttempt1, look2)) // 'even'
                        answer << "\n" << look2 << "2";
                };
            }
            //look for 'odd'36, 'odd'76, 'even'12, 'even'52, 'even'92
            //these are the possibilities for multiples of 8 ended with 2
            else if (ExistDigit(originalNumber, start, 6)) {
                for (int look2 = 3; look2 < 10; look2 += 4) {
                    int startAttempt1 = start;
                    if (ExistDigit(originalNumber, startAttempt1, look2)) { // 'odd'
                        for (int look3 = 1; look3 < 10; look3 += 2) {
                            int startAttempt2 = startAttempt1;
                            if (ExistDigit(originalNumber, startAttempt2, look3))
                                answer << "\n" << look3 << look2 << "6";
                        };
                    }
                };
                for (int look2 = 1; look2 < 10; look2 += 4) {
                    int startAttempt1 = start;
                    if (ExistDigit(originalNumber, startAttempt1, look2)) // 'even'
                        answer << "\n" << look2 << "6";
                };
            }
            //look for 'even'24, 'even'64, 'odd'44, 'odd'84, 'odd'04
            //these are the possibilities for multiples of 8 ended with 2
            else if (ExistDigit(originalNumber, start, 6)) {
                for (int look2 = 0; look2 < 10; look2 += 4) {
                    int startAttempt1 = start;
                    if (ExistDigit(originalNumber, startAttempt1, look2)) { // 'odd'
                        for (int look3 = 1; look3 < 10; look3 += 2) {
                            int startAttempt2 = startAttempt1;
                            if (ExistDigit(originalNumber, startAttempt2, look3))
                                answer << "\n" << look3 << look2 << "4";
                        };
                    }
                };
                for (int look2 = 2; look2 < 10; look2 += 4) {
                    int startAttempt1 = start;
                    if (ExistDigit(originalNumber, startAttempt1, look2)) // 'even'
                        answer << "\n" << look2 << "4";
                };
            }
        }
    }
    cout << answer.str() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a solution when you are looking for a subword composed of successive characters in the decimal textual form.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

bool ExistDigit(const std::string& number, int look) { // look1 = 2**look
    // look for a subword of size look that is divisible by 2**look = 1UL << look
    for (int i = (int) number.size()-1; i >= 0; --i) {
        bool hasFound = false;
        unsigned long val = 0;
        int shift = look-1;
        if (i-shift <= 0)
            shift = i;
        for (; shift >= 0; --shift) {
            val *= 10;
            val += (number[i-shift] - '0');
        };
        if (val % (1UL << look) == 0)
            return true;
    };
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::string val;
    std::cin >> val;
    if (ExistsDigit(val, 3) /* since 8 = 2**3 = (1 << 3) */)
        std::cout << "have found a decimal subword divisible by 8" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "have not found any decimal subword divisible by 8" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If you are likely to find a subword of consecutive bits in the binary form of the number, you need to convert your number in a big integer and then to do similar search.

Here is a (minimal-tested) solution without any call to an external library like gmp to convert the text in a big integer. This solution makes use of bitwise operations (`<<`, `&`).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int
ExistDigit(const std::string & currentNumber, int look) { // look1 = 2^look 
   std::vector<unsigned> bigNumber;
   int length = currentNumber.size();
   for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
       unsigned carry = currentNumber[i] - '0';
       // bigNumber = bigNumber * 10 + carry;
       for (int index = 0; index < bigNumber.size(); ++index) {
          unsigned lowPart = bigNumber[index] & ~(~0U << (sizeof(unsigned)*4));
          unsigned highPart = bigNumber[index] >> (sizeof(unsigned)*4);
          lowPart *= 10;
          lowPart += carry;
          carry = lowPart >> (sizeof(unsigned)*4);
          lowPart &= ~(~0U << (sizeof(unsigned)*4));
          highPart *= 10;
          highPart += carry;
          carry = highPart >> (sizeof(unsigned)*4);
          highPart &= ~(~0U << (sizeof(unsigned)*4));
          bigNumber[index] = lowPart | (highPart << (sizeof(unsigned)*4));
       }
       if (carry)
          bigNumber.push_back(carry);
   };
   // here bigNumber should be a biginteger = currentNumber

   for (int i = 0; i < bigNumber.size()*8*sizeof(unsigned); ++i) {
       // looks for look consective bits set to '0'
       bool hasFound = true;
       for (int shift = 0; hasFound && shift < look; ++shift)
           if (bigNumber[(i+shift) / (8*sizeof(unsigned))]
                   & (1U << ((i+shift) % (8*sizeof(unsigned)))) != 0)
               hasFound = false;

       if (hasFound) { // ok, bigNumber has look consecutive bits set to 0
           // test if we are at the end of the bigNumber
           int index = (i+look) / (8*sizeof(unsigned));
           for (int j = ((i+look+8*sizeof(unsigned)-1) % (8*sizeof(unsigned)))+1;
                   j < (8*sizeof(unsigned)); j++)
               if ((bigNumber[index] & (1U << j)) != 0)
                   return i; // the result is (currentNumber / (2^i));
           while (++index < bigNumber.size())
               if (bigNumber[index] != 0)
                   return i; // the result is (currentNumber / (2^i));
           return -1;
       };
   };
   return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   std::string val;
   std::cin >> val;
   std::cout << val << " is divided by 8 after " << ExistDigit(val, 3) << " bits." << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I will take some time to go over this because vector is a new library to me. I will reach out to you when I do. However, I would like to know if my option to use a bool method is bad in this case. I honestly did not  see anyone using it, but it seems convenient.

Comment: @MLaurentys your option to use a `bool` method is correct, but as the algorithm is complex, you need to verify it and to debug it. And it is not easy to verify it if it just returns `true` or `false`.

Comment: I believe I understand now. I believe it will work if I adapt my call and how I use returns value. I just believe it is a bit too complicate for me for now, but I will use this idea in the next code. Thank you A LOT. For this code specifically, while I was messing around with vectors I bumped into a function that solves the problem really fast and nicely. I think you know it, but the name is find_last_of (I can get the position of the char I am looking for). Again, thank you very much! 
Can you explain to me why you chose unsigned data type?

Comment: @MLaurentys I have a much simpler solution if you look a subword in the decimal textual form. I just change my post and I will add more explanation in 8h.

Comment: @MLaurentys unsigned data type is more adequate than signed data type for bitwise operations, especially when you want to split your number in two parts with shift and bitmask operations.

Comment: @MLaurentys I also missed the point that the subword may be composed with non consecutive characters.